# Inventory Out-File with a new row

Tags: windows, powershell

I have an Inventory Powershell script that I am trying to output into a csv. My goal is to output each execution of the script in a separate row going down their columns.

I've tried Export-Csv, but since i'm using variables, the csv displays (i'g guessing) metadata.

```
    $ComputerName =  Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem  | select -ExpandProperty CSName
    $OS_Name = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Caption 
    $OS_Architecture = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem  | select -ExpandProperty OSArchitecture
    $System_Manufacturer = Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem  | select -ExpandProperty Manufacturer
    $Model = Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem  | select -ExpandProperty Model
    $CPU_Manufacturer = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor  | select -ExpandProperty Name
    $Disk_Size_GB = Get-WmiObject win32_diskDrive  | Measure-Object -Property Size -Sum | % {[math]::round(($_.sum /1GB),2)}
    $Physical_Memory_GB = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_PhysicalMemory  | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum | % {[Math]::Round(($_.sum / 1GB),2)}
    $Version=(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" -Name ReleaseId).ReleaseId
    $InstallDate= systeminfo | find /I “Install Date”
    $Assettag=(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_SystemEnclosure | Select-Object SMBiosAssetTag).SMBiosAssetTag 
    $SerialNumber =  (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS | Select-Object SerialNumber).SerialNumber


  ($Assettag, $ComputerName, $System_Manufacturer, $Model, $OS_Name, $Version, $SerialNumber | Format-Table | Out-File C:\Users\1\Desktop\Newinvent.csv  )
```

I expect each row to be filled with each execution
Thanks

Comment: build a `[PSCustomObject]` with those items as _properties_. collect them into a collection, and finally feed that to `Export-CSV`. you will get a nice, neat CSV file ... [*grin*]

Comment: This is a horribly inefficient technique - you are calling WMI multiple times with the same class, so in several cases you already have the data you are about to query. Call WMi once-per-class and put the returned information into a variable, then use @Lee_Dailey 's suggestion to create a custom object that will export nicely with `Export-Csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Export-Csv`, you need to have an object with properties that contain the names and values you want to export. One way to do this is to create a `[PSCustomObject]` with all of your properties defined in a hash table. You can pipe that custom object to the `Export-Csv` command.

```
[PSCustomObject]@{"ComputerName" = $ComputerName
        "OS_Name" = $OS_Name
        "OS_Architecture" = $OS_Architecture
        "System_Manufacturer" = $System_Manufacturer
        "Model" = $Model
        "CPU_Manufacturer" = $CPU_Manufacturer
        "Disk_Size_GB" = $Disk_Size_GB
        "Physical_Memory_GB" = $Physical_Memory_GB
        "Version" = $Version
        "InstallDate" = $InstallDate
        "Assettag" = $Assettag
        "SerialNumber" = $SerialNumber
} | Export-Csv -Path file.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Answer (score 1):

And try to look at the result from Get-ComputerInfo - most of your needs are satisfied there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid the time consuming `Systeminfo`

```
> (Measure-Command {$systeminfo=(systeminfo) 2>$NULL}).Totalseconds
3,0428012
```

As well as `Get-ComputerInfo`

```
$OldProgressPreference = $ProgressPreference
$ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
(Measure-Command {$ComputerInfo = Get-ComputerInfo}).Totalseconds
3,1837208
$ProgressPreference = $OldProgressPreference
```

And use an optimized version of your script which gets/converts InstallDate from registry:

```
> (Measure-Command{Q:\Test\2019\06\03\SO_56429703.ps1}).TotalSeconds
1,635074
Get-Content file.csv
```

---

```
## Q:\Test\2019\06\03\SO_56429703.ps1

function RoundGB($Size){
  [math]::round(($Size/1GB),2)
}

$Win32OS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem
$Win32CS = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem
$CurrVer = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion'
$InstDate= [timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds(
           (Get-ItemProperty $CurrVer).InstallDate)

$inventory = [PSCustomObject]@{
    ComputerName      = $Win32OS.CSName
    OSName            = $Win32OS.Caption
    OSArchitecture    = $Win32OS.OSArchitecture
    SystemManufacturer= $Win32CS.Manufacturer
    Model             = $Win32CS.Model
    CPUManufacturer   = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor).Name
    DiskSizeGB        = RoundGB (Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive      | Measure-Object Size -Sum).Sum
    PhysicalMemoryGB  = RoundGB (Get-WMIObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object capacity -Sum).Sum
    Version           = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $CurrVer -Name ReleaseId).ReleaseId
    InstallDate       = $InstDate
    Assettag          = (Get-WmiObject Win32_SystemEnclosure).SMBiosAssetTag
    SerialNumber      = (Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS).SerialNumber
}
$Inventory | Export-Csv -Path file.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```